# How can I prevent material-ui Select options to be opened when clicking on particular area of the selected option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, onclick, material-ui

I've got a `Select` component from `@material-ui/core/Select`, with only one option (to simplify),
that I use like below:

```js
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Test</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
    id="demo-controlled-open-select"
    value={0}
    onChange={e => { console.log({ type: 'on-change', e }) }}
    onClick={e => { console.log({ type: "on-click", e }) }}
    onOpen={e => { console.log({ type: "on-open", e }) }}
  >
    <MenuItem value={0}>
      <div>
        <button onClick={e => { console.log({ type: "open-on-click", e }) }}>
          Open
        </button>
        <button onClick={e => {
          console.log({ type: "do-not-open-on-click", e })
          // Do something
          e.stopPropagation() // Try not to open the options
        }}>
          Do not open
        </button>
      </div>
    </MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

It gives the result ([see the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0trd8?file=/demo.tsx)):

[image]

When I click on one of the two buttons, it opens the `Select` options.
My question is: **how can I do not to open the `Select` options when clicking on the "Do not open" button?**
My problem seems that I am not able to catch the click event on the content of my `Select` component.
Therefore, my `e.stopPropagation()` has no effect.

I need to have such a behaviour because in my real use-case
I'd like to have a `TextField` component in place of my "Do not open" button for example.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `<Select />` controlled would be fine

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

<Select
  value={0}
  onClose={() => {
    setOpen(false);
  }}
  open={open}
>

<MenuItem value={0}>
  <div className="main-option">
    <button
      onClick={() => {setOpen(true)}}
    >
      Open
    </button>
    <button>
      Do not open
    </button>
  </div>
</MenuItem>
```

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

export default function ControlledOpenSelect() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Test</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
        id="demo-controlled-open-select"
        value={0}
        onOpen={e => {
          console.log({ type: "on-open"});
        }}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false)
        }}
        open={open}
      >
        <MenuItem value={0}>
          <div className="main-option">
            <button
              onClick={e => {
                console.log({ type: "open-on-click"});
                setOpen(true);
              }}
            >
              Open
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={e => {
                console.log({ type: "do-not-open-on-click"});
              }}
            >
              Do not open
            </button>
          </div>
        </MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Try it online:

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue.  
I did some changes in the demo so that: 1. dropdown's arrow opens the options & 2. textfield is focused after a click on it -> https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-s8nq5?file=/demo.tsx (it can be helpful)